# Can all all ability bonuses aside from weapons "+" effects be stacked?

Tags: eldritch-horror

By ability bonus, I mean any quality of an asset at all, not just the "+N" to an attribute. My question centers around how to compound effects on assets. The quick reference explains that weapon "Gain +N to " bonuses do not compound and that you simply pick the strongest one. Does this mean any non-weapon "+" bonus does compound, i.e. from items and allies for instance? Some example questions:

- If I have 3 assets that each grant +1 to an attribute, do I have +3 (in addition to my best weapon "+" bonus?
- If I have 3 assets that each say I can reroll a die, do I get 3 rerolls?
- Is there any other clear case aside from the weapon "+" bonus to attributes where assets are *not* compounded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) +N bonuses do not compound. From rules (Section Additional Rules - Tests p.12:

> An investigator can use only one card effect that provides a skill
>   bonus during each test (for example, an Asset that reads “Gain
>   +1 [”). If he has multiple card effects that provide a bonus, he
>   uses the highest bonus.

An ally is an asset just like a weapon, so having +1 to Strength from an ally and a +1 to Strength from a gun will result you in having a +1.

2) Yes. From reference guide (Section Reroll):

> If multiple effects allow an investigator to reroll a die, he may
>   resolve each effect separately. There is no limit to the number of
>   times a die or test can be rerolled, so long as the investigator has
>   the means to do so.

Comment: Can you tell me where you see that in the rules specifically? I see in the quick reference guide under Tests "He may use **one** effect that provides a bonus (for example "Gain +3 <will>"). If multiple effects provide a bonus, he uses only the highest bonus. This seems to support your answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It's on page 12 Additional Rules -> Tests Last paragraph. It seem the text from reference guide is slightly different and it does not mention a word asset.